# Default order with jQuery UI Sortable

Tags: jquery, mysql, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I have the following issue. I want to do the next thing. In the webpage I'm developing, when a user is logged, he has to arrange some variables and I need to save the order he arranged them. With this code I could get the order value of each item setting it in a hidden form input so when the user press "save" those valued are saved within a MySQL database. Until here it works fine:

```
$(document).ready(function() { $( function() {
    $( "#sortable" ).sortable( {
    placeholder: "ui-state-highlight",
    helper: 'clone',
    sort: function(e, ui) {
        $(ui.placeholder).html(Number($("#sortable > li:visible").index(ui.placeholder)) + 1);
    },
    update: function(event, ui) {
        var $lis = $(this).children('li');
        $lis.each(function() {
            var $li = $(this);
            var newVal = $(this).index() + 1;
            // $(this).children('.sortable-number').html(newVal);
            $(this).children('input').val(newVal);

        });
    } }
      );
    $( "#sortable" ).disableSelection();
       } ); } );
```

This is the output from PHP (each item look like this):

```
<li class="ui-state-default bookred"><input type="hidden" name="grammar1" value="<?php echo $grammar1 ?>"><a data-fancybox="" data-src="exercises/grammar-pronomen.php" href="javascript:;"><i class="fa fa-eye" aria-hidden="true"></i></a><a href="#" class="delete"><i class="fa fa-trash" aria-hidden="true"></i></a> <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Pronomen</li>
```

The problem comes when the user refreshes the webpage. The order he chose arranging the elements are not being respected. Getting the values from MySQL is not a problem, the problem is to set those values within the UI in order to get the items arranged as the user did so.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I would advise using whatever code you use to submit the form in an AJAX POST during `update`. In this way, the order is updated in the database when the user makes changes and not just when they submit the form. This may address your issue with the user refreshing, since the DB value will be different and PHP should pull the new value when the page is rendered.

Comment: You can cookie the values if you don't want to save in any changes (only by button), or you can AJAX the positions each time the user do it setting it directly to the database, to a temp table or into memory, session or anything like that.

Comment: Hi. In fact I need to save the changes. If the user log in the page in a further occasion, he needs to see the order of the values as he left them.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I could solve my problem with this code using a dynamic ID:

First I get the values saved within the MySQL database. Those values are the number order of each element. For instance: grammar1 = 2, grammar2 = 4 etc and I need those elements arranged by order.

```
$query = $DBcon->query("SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE name='$master'");
if ($query->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $query->fetch_assoc()) {
        $grammar1 = $row["grammar1"];
        $grammar2 = $row["grammar2"];
        $grammar3 = $row["grammar3"];
        // and so on...
   }
}
```

And if the value is not 0 (0 means that the user didn't select that element, so it has not to be printed) the value is printed as the ID like this:

```
    <ul id="sortable">
        <?php if ($grammar1 != 0){ ?>
            <li class="ui-state-default" id="<?php echo $grammar8 ?>">Any content</li>
        <?php } ?>
</ul>
```

And the following code rearrange the elements as the user saved it, and it works!

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var mylist = $('#sortable');
    var listitems = mylist.children('li').get();
    listitems.sort(function(a, b) {
        var compA = parseFloat($(a).attr('id'));
        var compB = parseFloat($(b).attr('id'));
        return (compA < compB) ? -1 : (compA > compB) ? 1 : 0;
    });        
    $.each(listitems, function(idx, itm) {
        mylist.append(itm);
    });
});
```